# Problems in plotting a function of two variables

Tags: plotting

Not able to generate the plot in following code. Kindly help to fix it

```
 a = Re[Sqrt[x^2 - 2 x y + y^2 - 1^2]];
mat = {{0, -a/Sqrt[(x - y)^2 + Abs[a]^2]}, {(x - y)/
     Sqrt[(x - y)^2 + Abs[a]^2], 0}};
d1 = D[mat, x];
d2 = Simplify[mat.d1, {x >= 0, y >= 0}];
fun[x_, y_] = 
  Simplify[Tr[d1.d1] + (1/Det[mat]) Tr[d2.d2], {x >= 0, y >= 0}];

Plot3D[fun[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: The derivative of `Re` is poorly defined. Try replacing Plot3D with Table in your code and you will see why you can't plot the resulting expression. You will have to fix the calculation first so Plot can obtain actual real numbers from fun. This is the exact same problem that was pointed out to you in your previous question you have since deleted [(238622)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/238622/no-plot-generated-for-this-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

a = Re[Sqrt[x^2 - 2 x y + y^2 - 1^2]];
```

You cannot take the derivative of a function which contains [`Re`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Re.html). Use [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) to avoid use of `Re`

```
mat = {{0, -a/Sqrt[(x - y)^2 + Abs[a]^2]}, {(x - y)/
       Sqrt[(x - y)^2 + Abs[a]^2], 0}} // 
    ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // Simplify;

d1 = D[mat, x];
d2 = Simplify[mat . d1, {x >= 0, y >= 0}];
fun[x_, y_] = Simplify[
   Tr[d1 . d1] + (1/Det[mat]) Tr[d2 . d2],
   {x >= 0, y >= 0}];

Plot3D[
  fun[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5},
  PlotPoints -> 75,
  MaxRecursion -> 5,
  ClippingStyle -> None] // Quiet
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Bob Hanlon. Just a small query. What is the meaning of # in {{0, -a/Sqrt[(x - y)^2 + Abs[a]^2]}, {(x - y)/
     Sqrt[(x - y)^2 + Abs[a]^2], 0}} // 
  ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // Simplify

Comment: I am not an expert in Mathematica, so plz help to "decode this code".

Comment: In Mathematica highlight `#` (or any other unknown symbol) and press `F1` for help.